# Sencha: Production build successful but app throws exception in Safari

Tags: exception, safari, sencha-touch, dev-to-production

My app runs fine in a development environment. Here is what I do to create a production build:

I Executed:

sencha create jsb -a index.html -p app.jsb3

Then

sencha build ­p app.jsb3 ­d ../production

The production build executes fine with no failures. When I try to open my app in Safari I get:

TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'Ext.getStore('MainStore').load')

As I said normally this code executes without a hitch, so I can't figure i!
I should add that the app starts in Safari because I see my first page load, so its definitely finding all my css and js files....its just choking when it gets to the line above.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure whether the code for loading store is Ext.getStore('MainStore').load(); itself